# CFRelease in for loop error: Incorrect decrement of the reference count of an object that is not owned at this point by the caller

Tags: release

When I release in for loop, Analyze show error:

> Incorrect decrement of the reference count of an object that is not
>   owned at this point by the caller

What am I doing wrong?

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < frameCount; ++i) {
  NSDictionary *dict = (NSDictionary*)CFBridgingRelease(CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(gifSource, i, NULL));

  NSDictionary *gifDict = [dict valueForKey:(NSString*)kCGImagePropertyGIFDictionary];
  [delayTimes addObject:[gifDict valueForKey:(NSString*)kCGImagePropertyGIFDelayTime]];
  totalTime = totalTime + [[gifDict valueForKey:(NSString*)kCGImagePropertyGIFDelayTime] floatValue];
  CFRelease((__bridge CFTypeRef)(dict)); //Analyze showgin error here.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> id __nullable CFBridgingRelease(CFTypeRef CF_CONSUMED __nullable X) {
>       return (__bridge_transfer id)X; }

I think I don't need CFRelease(dict) because I've transferred ownership to ARC in the __bridge_transfer